# Redshift: FULL JOIN leaving out NULLs for right table

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a `Table1` like this:

```
ID |   Name   | Occupation
----------------------------
 1 | Garfield | Student
```

and another `Table 2` like this:

```
ID |   Name   | Occupation
----------------------------
 1 | Garfield | Stud
```

My expected output is this:

```
Table1.ID |   Table1.Name   | Table1.Occupation | Table2.ID |   Table2.Name   | Table2.Occupation
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1        | Garfield        | Student           | NULL      |      NULL       |  NULL
NULL      | NULL            | NULL              | 1         |   Garfield      |  Stud
```

My query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
FULL JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
AND t1.name = t2.name
AND (t1.occupation ILIKE ('%' || t2.occupation || '%') OR t2.occupation ILIKE ('%' || t1.occupation || '%'))
;
```

But this query gives me the following output:

```
Table1.ID |   Table1.Name   | Table1.Occupation | Table2.ID |   Table2.Name   | Table2.Occupation
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1        | Garfield        | Student           | NULL      |      NULL       |  NULL
```

Where am I going wrong? Can someone help address this?

Comment: @asantz96: `ILIKE` is **not** the "opposite" of `LIKE`, it's a `LIKE` that is case in-sensitive.

Comment: @Garfield . . . Something is wrong with your results.  You should be seeing all rows from both tables at least once in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

The problem are in the last part of the `JOIN`. Move the last part to a `WHERE` clause.

Try this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
FULL JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
AND t1.name = t2.name
WHERE (t1.occupation ILIKE ('%' || t2.occupation || '%') OR t2.occupation ILIKE ('%' || t1.occupation || '%'));
```

**Note:** If Id is **Primary Key** you can ommit the second clause of the `JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
FULL JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE (t1.occupation ILIKE ('%' || t2.occupation || '%') OR t2.occupation ILIKE ('%' || t1.occupation || '%'));
```